# Etiquette for adding repository during rpm/deb install

Tags: linux, repository, debian, rpm

We're distributing a commercial application for Linux and we currently make it available for download as a .tar.gz, a .rpm, and a .deb.  We're setting up both RPM and DEB repositories to make upgrading easier.  Is it appropriate to add our repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/yum.repos.d` automatically as part of the initial install?  Are there any good reasons not to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a perfectly viable strategy to drop files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` and `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg` for the purpose of adding a yum repo. Many popular repos do exactly this. Editing a flat file such as `/etc/apt/sources.list` is trickier (especially on remove), but it can be done.

Comment: ...which is why you should add/remove your `.list` file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Debian policy manual

http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/

If it's not in there, discuss it on one of the Debian developer mailing lists.